# socket.gethostbyname fails when ipv6 is enabled

Tags: python, macos, sockets, ipv6

I'm having the strangest behavior in an office setting where I don't have access to the switch gear.  When IPv6 is enabled, socket.gethostbyname() fails and socket.getaddrinfo() returns only IPv6 addresses after a long 10 second timeout.  If I manually disable IPv6 and refresh the lease, they both start working.

Latest OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2 on a MBP using wired ethernet.  I noticed recently that you can't turn off IPv6, just set to link local.  You can turn it off using networksetup, but that only lasts until reboot.

Any ideas on how to track this down?  I think the problem is the switch and not my machine, but not sure where to look next.

My v4 DHCP service is set to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4.

```
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 74.125.131.99
www.google.com has address 74.125.131.103
www.google.com has address 74.125.131.104
www.google.com has address 74.125.131.147
www.google.com has address 74.125.131.106
www.google.com has address 74.125.131.105
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400c:c03::63
```

Here gethostbyname fails and getaddrinfo returns after a long timeout.

```
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('www.google.com', 80)
[(30, 2, 17, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::63', 80, 0, 0)), (30, 1, 6, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::63', 80, 0, 0)), (30, 2, 17, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::63', 80, 0, 0)), (30, 1, 6, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::63', 80, 0, 0)), (30, 2, 17, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::93', 80, 0, 0)), (30, 1, 6, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::93', 80, 0, 0))]
>>> ^D
```

Ping fails.

```
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.103
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.99
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.104
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.106
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.105
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.147
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400c:c03::93
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ ping www.google.com
ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host
```

Turn off IPV6:

```
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ sudo networksetup -setv6off Ethernet
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ ping www.google.com
ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.103
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.99
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.104
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.106
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.105
www.google.com has address 173.194.75.147
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400c:c03::68
```

Force the DHCP lease to renew, ping, gethostbyname, getaddrinfo all work fine.

```
(nimbis)bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.75.103): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.194.75.103: icmp_seq=0 ttl=46 time=25.218 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.75.103: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=23.944 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.75.103: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=24.213 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.75.103: icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=78.480 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.75.103: icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 time=24.502 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 23.944/35.271/78.480/21.608 ms
bschott@ironman:django-nimbis$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
'173.194.75.147'
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('www.google.com', 80)
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.131.106', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.131.147', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.131.106', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.131.99', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '',    ('74.125.131.99', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.131.104', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '',  ('74.125.131.104', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.131.105', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.131.105', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.131.103', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('74.125.131.103', 80)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('74.125.131.147', 80)), (30, 1, 6, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::93', 80, 0, 0)), (30, 2, 17, '', ('2607:f8b0:400c:c03::93', 80, 0, 0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a proper IPv4 address and default route if you have IPv6 enabled? It sort of sounds like you have NAT64 running with some weird setup. getaddrinfo will then not return IPv4 addresses if called with AI_ADDRCONFIG.

The `host` utility doesn't use the system lookup routines but rather it's own network code, so `dscacheutil -flushcache` won't affect it.